# gimp : move a curved text layer, not just only borders of selection

Tags: gimp, text, layers, text-on-path

I would like to move a curved text with Gimp. Here's below the current text to move (zoomed) :

[image: zoomed image showing text to move]

For instant, I can move it but after, the old text remains (filled in white) and I can just have the borders of new curved text (in blue), like this :

[image: Old text remains and new one is not filled]

How to make disappear the old text and fill the new one (in white) ?

Or maybe there is a way to move directly the curved text without having to move borders and after fill it ?

I am using the following "move tool options" :

[image: Move tool options]

I have to precise that I am on MacOS 10.9.5

Any help is welcome, regards

Comment: Strange because what you move (the blue outline) is the path ("tracé", in French) but that would be the rightmost icon in the "Move/Déplacer" choice in the Tool options. Furthermore that path is obviously too big to have generated the curved text in white? And the big question is whether the white text is on its own layer (easy to delete, just remove the layer) or is already merged into the background (hard to delete cleanly). Anyway, it would be easier to recreate it (and it would have the right curvature).

Comment: @xenoid How can I have access to the layer box into gimp ? It's been a long time that I have created the original image and I don't remenber where I can handle layers

Comment: Windows>Dockable dialogs>Layers or Ctrl-L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you move the blue outline you are only moving the path. That's how GIMPs text on a path works - it basically just generates a path. The text is separate, and will not move with the path.

In your example, you'd need to erase the text layer first (assuming it has one), add a new layer, move the path, turn the path to a selection again, and then fill it.

If the text is not on its own layer, you could erase it by painting over it - but that won't be easy if there is a gradient background like your example.

You'd be better using Inkscape (a vector image editor) for this kind of work. GIMP is not really the right kind of software for this.